# Получение текста элемента JS

Tags: javascript

Пишу скрипт для браузера на js. Не получается получить текст элементов. Выдает undefined. Так же пробовал с .text, .textContent, всё равно не работает

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("item__inner")
for ( key in elements ){
    alert(key.textContent)
}
```

Comment: используй jQuery

Comment: `innerHTML` ???

Comment: @MoloF есть теоретический вопрос - поможешь ?

Comment: @MaximLensky конечно

Comment: @MoloF вот смотри - я вернулся из зоны карантина, там есть ограничения на интернет, максимум что там получил это 3G с двумя палками антены, так вот ни один сайт не грузится...может ли быть такое что из за обилия javascript не грузятся сайты ?

Comment: @MaximLensky `JS` имеет нагрузку конечно, но в наших реалиях сборщик оптимизирует код и вес там будет ничтожно мал, в основном вес сайта будет сильно зависеть от растрового изображения, сколько верстаю, картинки большая проблема, стараюсь использовать векторные иконки и поменьше растра, для того чтобы сайт грузился в первую очередь быстрее. Мой проект на `VueJS` с использованием `PWA`, весит 2,08 МБ. 1.7мб весит весь бандл `JS`, остальное стили и картинки, но не видел в своей жизни бандл превышающий 10 мегабайт..

Comment: @MoloF в данный момент я говорю о SO и о Toster, они текстовые картинки на этих сайтах сам знаешь мизирные ...что за косяк ? раньше же когда 4G был в проекте а 3G был ВАУ сайты же открывались ..

Comment: @MaximLensky у меня 600кб загружается при открытии вкладки. Я сам сижу с 3g когда приезжаю домой, грузит все равно все моментально, не знаю даже в чем проблема, может кто-то еще подпитывается вашим трафиком? Расширения например, плюс еще не мало важно ваше местоположение, чем дальше от самого сервера, тем больше будет пинг

Comment: @MoloF всё таки наверно это спец органы блочат ...

Comment: @MaximLensky и это тоже имеет место быть, ваш трафик может фильтроваться службами и это очень сильно будет ощущаться на скорости загрузки страницы

Comment: @MoloF я тоже так думал - спасибо за беседу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По просьбе ТС'a составил небольшой пример того, как можно распарсить данные со [страницы](https://csgoempire.gg/withdraw):

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".items-grid .item__inner");

for (element of elements){
  const image = element.querySelector('.item__image-inner img').src;
  const price = element.querySelector('.coinstack + span').innerHTML.replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ');
  console.log(image, price);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Потому что вот:

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("item__inner")
for ( key in elements ){
  console.log(key);
}
```

```html
<div class="item__inner">111</div>
<div class="item__inner">222</div>
<div class="item__inner">333</div>
```

Сами элементы можно достать через `elements[key]`, но список элементов в прнципе не надо перебирать через `for...in`, т.к. туда помимо элементов, попадают и другие свойства объекта.

Можно использовать классический цикл, или, `querySelectorAll` имеет встроенный метод `forEach`

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll(".item__inner");

for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  console.log(elements[i].textContent, i);
}

console.log('- - -');

elements.forEach(function(elem, i) {
  console.log(elem.textContent, i);
});
```

```html
<div class="item__inner">111</div>
<div class="item__inner">222</div>
<div class="item__inner">333</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Во-первых, не `in`, а `of`.

Во-вторых, используйте `innerHTML`.

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("item__inner")
for ( key of elements ){
    console.log(key.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<div class="item__inner">text1</div>
<div class="item__inner">text2</div>
<div class="item__inner">text3</div>
<div class="item__inner">text4</div>
<div class="item__inner">text5</div>
```

---

Ответ на основе второго вопроса:

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".item__inner")
for (element of elements ){
  const price = element.querySelector('.price').innerHTML;
  console.log(price);
}
```

```html
<div class="item__inner">
  <div class="name">Name 1</div>
  <div class="price">100</div>  
</div>
<div class="item__inner">
  <div class="name">Name 2</div>
  <div class="price">200</div>  
</div>
<div class="item__inner">
  <div class="name">Name 3</div>
  <div class="price">300</div>  
</div>
<div class="item__inner">
  <div class="name">Name 4</div>
  <div class="price">400</div>  
</div>
<div class="item__inner">
  <div class="name">Name 5</div>
  <div class="price">500</div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

В данном случае key этот ключ (тип число) Вашего псевдомассива

Нужно заменить `alert(key.textContent)` на `alert(elements[key].textContent)`

Answer (score -2):

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("item__inner")
for ( key of elements ){
    console.log(key.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<div class="item__inner">text1</div>
<div class="item__inner">text2</div>
<div class="item__inner">text3</div>
<div class="item__inner">text4</div>
<div class="item__inner">text5</div>
```

Я понял проблему того кода. Но у меня сейчас новая проблема. Я получил innerHtml, и пытаюсь получить от туда элементы по имени класса. В ответ получаю ошибку:

```
VM3019:6 Uncaught TypeError: item_html.getElementsByClassName is not a function
    at <anonymous>:6:27
```

Вот мой код:

```
{
    items_htmls_array = document.getElementsByClassName('item__inner')
    for (key in items_htmls_array){
        item_html = items_htmls_array[key].innerHTML
        price = item_html.getElementsByClassName("text-sm font-bold text-light-grey-2")[0].innerText
    }
```

Comment: Это место предназначено для ответов. Задайте новый вопрос.

Comment: `item_html` - это строка. У строки нет метода `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: `key.getElementsByClassName("text-sm font-bold text-light-grey-2")[0].innerText` ?

Comment: А как получить из items_htmls_array[key] переменную типа document? Чтобы можно было найти элемент по имени класса?

Comment: Это место предназначено для ответов. Задайте новый вопрос.

Comment: @ЛёняДекарт проверьте мой вопрос, либо предоставьте побольше вашего `HTML` кода чтобы составить более точный ответ.

Comment: @MoloF В новом ответе предоставил источник HTML кода и свой код

Comment: @ЛёняДекарт оставил в новом ответе пример того как получить картинку и цену

Comment: Большой спасибо за помощь! Немного понял работу querySelector и получил данные всех остальных элементов. Напишу, если будут вопросы ещё.

Answer (score -2):

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("item__inner")
for ( key of elements ){
    console.log(key.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<div class="item__inner">text1</div>
<div class="item__inner">text2</div>
<div class="item__inner">text3</div>
<div class="item__inner">text4</div>
<div class="item__inner">text5</div>
```

Я понял проблему того кода. Но у меня сейчас новая проблема. Я получил innerHtml, и пытаюсь получить от туда элементы по имени класса. В ответ получаю ошибку:

```
VM3019:6 Uncaught TypeError: item_html.getElementsByClassName is not a function
    at <anonymous>:6:27
```

Вот мой код:

```
{
    items_htmls_array = document.getElementsByClassName('item__inner')
    for (key in items_htmls_array){
        item_html = items_htmls_array[key].innerHTML
        price = item_html.getElementsByClassName("text-sm font-bold text-light-grey-2")[0].innerText
    }
```

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".item__inner")
for (element of elements ){
  const price = element.querySelector('.price').innerHTML;
  console.log(price);
}
```

```html
<div class="item__inner">
  <div class="name">Name 1</div>
  <div class="price">100</div>  
</div>
<div class="item__inner">
  <div class="name">Name 2</div>
  <div class="price">200</div>  
</div>
<div class="item__inner">
  <div class="name">Name 3</div>
  <div class="price">300</div>  
</div>
<div class="item__inner">
  <div class="name">Name 4</div>
  <div class="price">400</div>  
</div>
<div class="item__inner">
  <div class="name">Name 5</div>
  <div class="price">500</div>  
</div>
```

Там нет элементов с классом PRICE.

```
var url = document.location.href; 
if (url == 'https://csgoempire.gg/withdraw'){
    items_htmls_array = document.getElementsByClassName('item__inner')
    for (item_html of items_htmls_array){
        price = item_html.getElementsByTagName('span')

    }
}
```

От каждого itemvar url = document.location.href;

```
if (url == 'https://csgoempire.gg/withdraw'){
    items_htmls_array = document.getElementsByClassName('item__inner')
    for (item_html of items_htmls_array){
        price = item_html.getElementsByTagName('span')

    }
}
```

Мне нужно получить информацию о каждом item_html . А именно:
Название, цену и качество. Но как я не пытался получить цену какого-то элемента, в ответ я получал пустые массивы или текст из других тегов.

Comment: Это место предназначено для ответов. Задайте новый вопрос.